# Guardar datos en localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, local-storage

necesito ayuda con un proyecto de universidad, en el siguiente codigo de javascript, la idea es como una pagina web que saca la informacion de personas (en una base de datos no real) la cual por cada foto de persona, se pueden hacer comentarios y dar likes, a cada comentario se le puede responder con otro comentario, tambien tiene la funcion de hacer su busqueda. El problema aqui es que me gustaria guardar esa informacion de los comentarios en el local storage (asi como se guarda el de las personas) y que cada que se recargue la pagina, se vuelvan a mostrar los comentarios, los likes y las "respuetas" de los comentarios, tambien que se pueda seguir actualizando. Me recomendaron algo asi como que no se guarda en un JSON si no que se guarda en un arreglo, que va directo en el codigo y ese arreglo va directo a las personas sin embargo ya intente de todo y no me funciona. Alguien me podria ayudar por favor?, llevo dias atorado y esto es para mañana, eh aqui el codigo js y el html:

```
const lista = document.querySelector(".lista");
const buscador = document.querySelector(".buscador");
const contenedorPrincipal = document.querySelector(".contenedor-principal");
const arregloPrincipal = [];

// Obtener datos de usuarios
obtenerDatos();

// Evento de búsqueda
buscador.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    arregloPrincipal.forEach(item => {
        const nombre = item.getAttribute("name");
        if (nombre.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())) {
            item.classList.remove("hide");
            item.classList.add("show");
        } else {
            item.classList.remove("show");
            item.classList.add("hide");
        }
    });
});

// Función para obtener datos (usuarios)
async function obtenerDatos() {
    let datosGuardados = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('usuarios2'));
   
    if (!datosGuardados) {
        const resultado = await fetch("https://randomuser.me/api?results=30");
        const { results } = await resultado.json();
        datosGuardados = [];

        results.forEach(user => {
            const divUsuario = crearUsuario(user);
            datosGuardados.push(user);
            arregloPrincipal.push(divUsuario);
            lista.appendChild(divUsuario);
        });

        localStorage.setItem('usuarios2', JSON.stringify(datosGuardados));
    }
    else {
        datosGuardados.forEach(data => {
            const divUsuario = crearUsuario(data);
            arregloPrincipal.push(divUsuario);
            lista.appendChild(divUsuario);
        });
    }
}

// Función para crear la estructura de usuario
function crearUsuario(data) {
    const divUsuario = document.createElement("div");
    const divComentarios = document.createElement("div");
    const imagen = document.createElement("img");
    const h1 = document.createElement("h1");
    const input = document.createElement("input");

    const nombreCompleto = data.name.first + " " + data.name.last;
    h1.textContent = nombreCompleto;
    imagen.setAttribute("src", data.picture.large);
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    divUsuario.setAttribute("name", nombreCompleto);
    divUsuario.classList.add("usuario");

    divComentarios.classList.add("contenedor");
    divUsuario.appendChild(imagen);
    divUsuario.appendChild(h1);
    divUsuario.appendChild(input);
    divUsuario.appendChild(divComentarios);

    input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
        comentario(event, divComentarios);
    });

    // Devolver un objeto con ambos elementos
    return divUsuario

}
    function comentario(event, contenedor) {
        const divUsuario = document.createElement("div");
        const divComentarios = document.createElement("div");
        divUsuario.appendChild(divComentarios);
    
        if (event.key == "Enter" && event.target.value !== "") {
            const nuevoComentario = {
                texto: event.target.value,
                noLikes: 0
            };
            event.target.value = "";
    
            const comentarioDiv = document.createElement("div");
            const botonLikes = document.createElement("button");
            const botonComentar = document.createElement("button");
            const inputComentario = document.createElement("input"); // Nuevo input
    
            comentarioDiv.classList.add("comentario");
            comentarioDiv.textContent = nuevoComentario.texto;
            botonLikes.textContent = nuevoComentario.noLikes + ": Likes";
            botonComentar.textContent = "Comentar";
            inputComentario.setAttribute("type", "text"); // Configurar el tipo de input
            inputComentario.setAttribute("placeholder", "Escribe un comentario"); // Placeholder
    
            botonLikes.addEventListener("click", function() {
                nuevoComentario.noLikes++;
                botonLikes.textContent = nuevoComentario.noLikes + ": Likes";
            });
    
            botonComentar.addEventListener("click", function() {
                if (inputComentario.value !== "") {
                    // Llamar a la función comentario nuevamente con el valor del nuevo input
                    comentario({ key: "Enter", target: { value: inputComentario.value} }, contenedor);
                    inputComentario.value = ""; // Limpiar el input después de enviar el comentario
                }
            });
    
            inputComentario.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
                if (event.key === "Enter") {
                    // Simular clic en el botón Comentar cuando se presiona Enter
                    botonComentar.click();
                }
            });
    
            comentarioDiv.classList.add("comentario");
            inputComentario.classList.add("comentario");
    
            comentarioDiv.appendChild(botonLikes);
            comentarioDiv.appendChild(botonComentar);
            comentarioDiv.classList.add("respuesta-comentario"); // Agregar la clase de identación
            contenedor.appendChild(comentarioDiv);
            contenedor.appendChild(inputComentario); // Agregar el nuevo input al contenedor
        }
    
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Persona 5</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input tXype="text" class="buscador">
    </div>
    <div class="lista">

    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Anexo codigo que hace la funcion que necesito, solo que no se como adaptarla

```
let boton = document.querySelector(".boton");
hacerCajas();
boton.addEventListener("click", function(){
    cajaTexto= document.querySelector(".texto");

    misnotas=localStorage.getItem("notas");//JSON

    if(misnotas==null){
        //Nadie a agregado notas
        arreglo=[];
    }else{
        arreglo=JSON.parse(misnotas);

    }
    arreglo.push(cajaTexto.value);
    cajaTexto.value="";
    localStorage.setItem("notas",JSON.stringify(arreglo));
    hacerCajas();
})

function hacerCajas(){
    misnotas=localStorage.getItem("notas");//JSON
    if(misnotas==null){
        //Nadie a agregado notas
        arreglo=[];
    }else{
        arreglo=JSON.parse(misnotas);

    }  
    codigoHtml="";
    arreglo.forEach((element, i) => {
        codigoHtml=codigoHtml+
        `<h1>NOTAS</h1>
        <p>${element} </p>
        <button id=${i} onclick="eliminar(this.id)">Eliminar</button>`
    });
    var cajaPrincipal=document.querySelector(".misnotas");
    cajaPrincipal.innerHTML=codigoHtml;

}
```

Comment: No entiendo exactamente tu problema. Pretendes tener un array en el código que persista los comentarios de un día para otro? Eso es imposible. El código te lo descargas del servidor cada vez, y por mucho que pudieses editarlo, la siguiente vez que accedas a la página estaría "limpio" otra vez. En cuanto a guardarlos en localStorage, cual es el problema? Ya estás guardando otras cosas ahí, es exactamente lo mismo

Comment: @Benito-B, lo que necesito es que esos comentarios que se agregan a la respectiva persona con el input, se vuelvan a mostrar en la interfaz aunque se recargue la pagina, lo que hace el codigo que puse, es que agrega los comentarios pero una vez recargas la pagina, se borran y ya no se muestran.

Comment: Añadire un codigo que hace la funcion que necesito hacer, solo que no se como adaptarla realmente

Answer (score 0):

puedes utilizar JSON.stringify([aqui va el arrego]) para convertir tu arreglo en un string y luego pasarlo al localStorage y para recuperarlo utiliza JSON.parse(aqui va el resultado del localStorage) para convertirlo en objeto de javaScript

JSON.parse() sirve para parsear un Json a un objeto javaScrip
JSON.stringify() sirve para parsear un objeto javaScript a un string de tipo json